# Will primary key violation ever occur due to state of rows during query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given this simple table with a composite primary key,

**Note**: none of the columns are auto increment identity - all the numbering is manual

**Note2**: the context of this question is in writing an update script to be applied at build time, not run-time.  It's inserting a static entry into a list of ordered items.

[image]

I find the following query succeeds in renumbering a select set of rows (the idea is to make room for an insert while keeping id2 as an ordered sequence).

```
update t
set id2 = id2 + 1
where id1 = 2 and id2 > 1
```

At some point during the execution of the above query, there is actually a primary key violation, but it does not cause a failure in my tests, which use **SQL Server 2012**.

This leads me to believe the primary key constraint is checked after all of the updates.

Is this something that varies from DBMS to DBMS or is this a given due to the transnational nature of SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no PK violation during this query execution. It works like this (simplified):

1. SQL Server searches for rows where id1 = 2 and id2 > 1
2. Calculates id2 + 1
3. Updates table

If your statement would break constraint, it will be detected at step 3.

You can read more on logical query processing. Rules are the same and not DBMS-dependent, but physical implementation differs.

Comment: would it be possible to include a link to some reference material on this?

Comment: I'd suggest Itzik Ben-Gan, [books](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/index.htm)
T-SQL Fundamentals or T-SQL Querying. Can't find decent link on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The PK auto-increment field is guaranteed to be unique within the column, but not necessarily contiguous.

However there are absolutely NO GUARANTEES for the uniqueness of any sort of PK you calculate yourself.

If you need a numeric PK, simply set the Identity property and let the server do it's job.

Renumbering rows is going to be a really bad idea, unless the DB is in single-user mode. Anything else is just begging for trouble, and in fact given the way the DB does caching, I don't believe it would be reliable even if you were the only user.

Comment: i updated my question to include the detail that I'm not using auto increment columns

Comment: >  i updated my question to include the detail that I'm not using auto increment columns